# Easy way to get hyperlink info from rendered web page

Tags: browser, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-rendering

I'd like do this programmatically:

Given a page URL, I need to get all links on the page. What's important is that at least 3 pieces of link info must be obtained: anchor text, `href` attribute value, absolute position of the link on the page.

Java CSSBox library is an option, but it's not fully implemented yet(the `href` attribute value cannot be obtained at the same time and some extra mapping must be done with additional library such as Jsoup). What's more, the CSSBox library renders a page really slow.

It seems that Javascript has all functions available but we have to inject the javascript code into the page and write a driver to take advantage of existing browsers. Scripting languages such as Python and Ruby have support for this as well. It is hard for me to find out the most handy tool.

Comment: Why can't it be a solution like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup

Comment: @AndréRicardo Thanks, but how can I get the absolute position of the link?

Comment: then maybe this is what you are looking for, a way to join the base_url and the relative_url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499603/python-scrapy-convert-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does PHP's DOM manipulation library help you? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: If it won't render the page, I don't think it works. I need the absolute position of link element on the page as well.

Comment: @TerryLi sorry I missed that part, may be you could try using http://phantomjs.org/