# How to get the hostname of the request?

Tags: python, scrapy

Sometimes when I scrape a site, it does not return urls with the hostname (e.g /search/en or search/en). How do I get the hostname in scrapy so I can add it before making a request? Currently, I am hardcoding it.

```
def parse_table(self, response):
    for links in self._parse_xpath(response, 'table'):
        for link in links:
            # Annoying part, it's not dynamic and hardcoded, other 
            #functions also need to do this because of incomplete urls.
            yield Request(url='https://domain.io' + link,
                        callback=self.parse_document_tab)
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: What are you using to scrape a site e.g. the scrapy code? what have you tried so far and are you getting any errors or is it just not working correctly in that instance?

Comment: @raffamaiden Whats an MWE?

Comment: @KyhleOhlinger Scrapy is working fine but it is annoying to have to deal with different urls before parsing them into requests. Heres a snipped on post.

Comment: So if i'm correct you want to get the full URL? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499603/python-scrapy-convert-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths ?

Comment: The solution I want to have is to have a url resolver that adds the collected url to the referer if it does not have a / in front and adding the collected url to the domain if it have a / . Problem is I can't find any methods to get the hostname or referers.

Comment: @KyhleOhlinger That is very useful. I actually have not check on that.

Comment: @KyhleOhlinger love it, that is just what I need! Thank you!

Comment: @KuoChongYii glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [`response.urljoin`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) method to join your relative URL to the base URL:

```
def parse_table(self, response):
    for links in self._parse_xpath(response, 'table'):
        for link in links:
            yield Request(url=response.urljoin(link),
                          callback=self.parse_document_tab)
```

Or the brand new [`response.follow`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow) (Scrapy 1.4.0+) method, that builds the proper absolute URL and returns a `Request` object:

```
def parse_table(self, response):
    for links in self._parse_xpath(response, 'table'):
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_document_tab)
```

Comment: I will use the second method just because it's newer. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: another advantage of the second method is that it works even if `link` is not a string. if it's a `Selector` object wrapping an `a` element, `.follow` will extract the `href` from that element for you.